# AWStats doesn't recognize any search engine

Tags: search-engine, keyword, awstats

AWStats seems to recognize Google as an external page rather than a
search engine.

As a result, it does not report top search keyphrases and keywords.

Output on the web page:

```
...
Links from an Internet Search Engine - Full list

Links from an external page (other web sites except search engines) - Full list
- http://www.google.com/url     1,427   1,427
- http://www.google.com/imgres  960     1,025
- http://www.google.com/search  332     367
...
```

Where should I look to find a solution?

Comment: I believe this can happen if you have LevelForSearchEnginesDetection set to 0 in the configuration file for your site. That being said, I have it set to 2 in mine, and am having the same problem. =/ Did you ever find a more correct solution?